# Reducir tamaño imagen enlazada mediante CSS

Tags: css, imagen

Intento reducir el tamaño de una imagen que tomo de una URL mediante CSS y no me deja, paso la URL de la página e imágenes del código especifico, agradezco sugerencias:
URL: http://3.84.104.198/

Como prueba la metí dentro de un div al cual le coloque el nombre de clase que tiene la etiqueta img, dándole dimensiones al div y colocando dimensiones en auto a la img pero nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías poner tu código como texto?

Answer (score 1):

En tu código había un error.

```
<img class="small" id="smart_thumbnail""  src="https://www.alfabetizaciondigital.redem.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/filos-1050x600.jpg">
```

Tienes comillas duplicadas seguido de tu identificador.

He hecho una prueba en [Codepen](https://codepen.io/slowdmelendez360/pen/bGemPpp) arreglando ese pequeño error y parece que ha funcionado.

[Ejemplo Codepen](https://codepen.io/slowdmelendez360/pen/bGemPpp)

Comment: Tienes razón, aunque mi problema es que la clase small no es afectada cuando aplico cambios en css.

Comment: Aunque suene tonto, deberías revisar si tu archivo css está bien indexado, porque no tuve ningún problema al hacerlo en mi ordenador.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en un servidor Linux remotamente, la cuestión es que hay otro archivo css que no puedo modificar ni eliminar por obligatoriedad, el que puedo modificar es que cree y estoy modificando.

Comment: Pero si la clase no existe en el otro archivo CSS no debería de haber problema.